# What is the C++ convention, if any, for naming to differentiate between structure types and other types?

Tags: c++, coding-style, coding-standards, visual-studio-2012

In general, should I use some sort of convention for structure names which is distinct from other type name? I was thinking about this when my professor started talking about structures.

I had the following discussion with myself, and since I do not want to come to any unreliable conclusions. How would you answer the question(s) and which answer(s) are untrustworthy?

Q: Should I distinguish structure names and type names to make the code more clear?

A: A structure is a type, so there doesn't need to be a distinction.

RE: Q: So there is never a case when someone uses `typedef int SOMETYPE` to rename a built-in type to make the code more flexible?

RE: A: There is no practical reason to rename built-in types. Actually, defining `int` types as `SOMETYPE` makes the code less readable because someone reading the code will not know the built-in type used for that type.

Honestly I do not trust either answer. Looking at some of the base structure in a new Win32Project using Visual Studio, I see things like `typedef short HFILE;` which, I guess, makes it more clear to the programmer what the variable is used for. Perhaps that is too subjective however.

As an aside, how does one usually determine what is going on when they come across variable declarations which use types you have never seen before. Do you just rely on the IDE to take you to or display the declaration?

Comment: The reasons behind so many Windows data types are explained here - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5144507/windows-data-types-why-so-redundant-undescriptive. In short- "1)they're historical types preserved for backward compatibility
2)they're different names for the same type that arose from different teams of developers."

Comment: Standard library's convention is macros all uppercase, underscore separated words and everything else all lowercase, underscore separated words, no prefixes for anything.

Comment: "There is no practical reason to rename built-in types". Seriously? What about multi-platform?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In C++ structs and classes are equivalent, except that the default visibility for struct members is public, while for classes it is private.  The following are equivalent:

```
struct X { private: int i; }
```

and

```
class X { int i; }
```

There is no reason to give structs a special prefix.

Also, just because something is in the Win32 API doesn't make it a good idea

Perhaps `typedef short HFILE` was useful for a C API, in case they later wanted to change to `typedef int HFILE`.  It's a poor practice for C++, where you could write:

```
struct HFILE { short s; }
```

This would allow passing HFILEs around by value as efficiently as shorts, while preventing unwanted conversion between an HFILE and numeric types.

Comment: That brings up a good point. Wouldn't it be better instead of writing `typedef short HFILE` you could do `#define HFILE short`? And I am glad you mention that HFILE can be converted undesirably, that is a useful pitfall to be aware of. Are you also then implying that a structure will never be converted. And I am having trouble finding an example code where HFILE will be converted.

Comment: @Leonardo: Avoid `#define` in C++ code. Use `typedef` or `using` for types, anonymous enums for numeric constants, templates and inline functions for expressions.

Comment: @Leonardo: Structure can't be converted except by explicitly provided conversion constructors and operators; you only provide the ones that really, really make sense, which is usually none.

Comment: I would go even further and say that most conventions used in Win32 API are rather bad ideas.

Comment: @Jan: I believe your opinion is shared by the majority of expert C/C++ programmers with experience beyond Windows.  Even given Microsoft's backward compatibility problems, it's hard to see why the Win32 API is so ugly compared to POSIX.